# Huawei - android multi-channel packaging

Tags: gradle, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

The agconnect-services.json is placed under the app, but if I want to package the user’s Google flavors through multiple channels, what should I do? In a project, I have to do two apps and two sets of package names, so two pushes require two agconnect-services.json Put it in the app file?

Comment: You can perform configuration according to [this doc](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor-android-0000001057944603) to see if it is helpful.